# Cannot find RTP payload for encoded audio

Tags: java, android, network-programming, sipdroid

I am trying to encrypt Sipdroid, and to do that I have to encrypt the the RTP packet after it gets the encoded audio payload. I am using this function in RTP packet class:

```
public byte[] getPayload() {
    int header_len = getHeaderLength();
    int len = packet_len - header_len;

    byte[] payload = new byte[len];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        payload[i] = packet[header_len + i];

    return payload;
}
```

The problem is that I cannot find where the rtp packet class is getting the payload as the RTP runs over UDP. I have gone through the UDP socket class but it is not there.

I think one way could be to get the datagram payload from the rtp packet and encrypt it.

Where is the RTP packet class getting its payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
RTPPacket packet;
byte payload[] = packet.getpayload;
```

it will return you the RTPpayload in the payload variable